# when using CPAN in linux ubuntu should I run it using sudo / as root or as my default user

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, configuration, installation

I get errors like this

```
Running make install
Prepending blib/arch and blib/lib of 17 build dirs to PERL5LIB; for 'install'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/local/man/man3'
Do not have write permissions on '/usr/local/man/man3'
```

```
  You may have to su to root to install the package
  (Or you may want to run something like
    o conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
```

Will I still be able to run the software / library's that perl / CPAN installs as a my default user.

What is the best practice when working with CPAN / Perl on Debian like systems.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should run the `cpan` command as your normal user.  You have two choices:

1. Install modules into a directory under your home dir.  [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) will help you set that up.
2. Configure `cpan` to use `sudo` during the install phase.  You do that by starting the `cpan` shell and typing:

   ```
   o conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
   o conf mbuild_install_build_command 'sudo ./Build'
   o conf commit
   ```

   The first line configures [MakeMaker](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker) to use `sudo`.  The second line does the same for [Module::Build](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build).  The third line saves the changes.

Comment: I think adding sudo to the make command will follow the programmers rule of least effort. So CPAN can build with out permission errors. I won't have to hack around to get things working.

Comment: Those aren't the only two options. You can set the destination directories to have the proper ownership, groups, or permissions so you don't have to sudo. That's why Unix has all that stuff. :)

Comment: This article was useful for me as well: http://learnperl.scratchcomputing.com/tutorials/configuration/

Answer (score 8):

If you want to install your modules for your own use, then you should be running it as yourself. Use [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/module/local::lib) to set up your environment variables so that this works nicely. You may wish to look at [cpan minus](https://metacpan.org/module/cpanm) as an alternative to the default cpan installer.

You may also wish to consider using [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) to install a newer version of perl that is completely independent from the system perl.

If you want to install them system wide, then I recommend (since you have tagged this *ubuntu*) looking at [dh-make-perl](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/78) to produce .deb files that you can install and uninstall with dpkg.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install modules as a non-root user, you can configure your cpan to use an install base:

```
makepl_arg         [INSTALL_BASE=/home/nelaar/perl]
mbuildpl_arg       [--install_base=/home/nelaar/perl]
```

And set PERL5LIB accordingly to `/home/nelaar/perl/lib/perl5`.